# Can I enable FIPS 140-2 only for some selected Docker (podman) containers? For automated testing purposes only

Tags: docker, automated-tests, fedora, fips, podman

For the purposes of testing my application under FIPS 140-2 environment, I thought of running a fipsed container.

Is this possible to do, without putting the entire host machine into FIPS mode, and having all containers be running under FIPS restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't *believe* this is possible. Not only do certain libraries (like openssl) expect "magic" files to be bind-mounted from the (FIPS-mode) host, but they also check `/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled`.  The former could maybe be faked in a container, but doing that with the later (proc files) sounds dangerous.

Ref this comment: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/9193#issuecomment-791928427